# rejecting for the wrapper promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm suspecting there's some problem with the code and it's most likely in the catch portion which altogether is crashing the server application.

**Objective**: Basically checking type of the error that can be handled for instance if entity doesn't exists, for all the other errors, reject them back to the caller gracefully without crashing the application.

```
const Article = require("Article");

function upload(row) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        Article.requestData(row.schema) // if exists
            .then(Article.upload.bind(null, row.article)) //may throw error
            .then(resolve) // done if OK
            .catch(function(error){
                if(error.code == "NotFoundException") { // entity doesn't exists
                    Article.create(row.schema) // create entity
                        .then(Article.upload.bind(null, row.article)) // upload
                        .then(resolve, reject); // reject upload error
                } else { // upload errors
                    // reject(error); // tried reject
                    throw error; // trying re-throw
                }
            });
    });
}
```

The code first tries to get info on the entity and if it's not found then it creates it.

Now the upload portion may throw an error that i need to send back to the caller gracefully.

The error I'm getting is `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Answer (score 0):

Same code, but rewritten.

```
function upload(row) {

   return Article.requestData(row.schema) // if exists
     .then(Article.upload.bind(null, row.article)) //may throw error
     .catch(function(error){
        if(error.code == "NotFoundException") { // entity doesn't exists
           return Article.create(row.schema) // create entity
             .then(Article.upload.bind(null, row.article)) // upload
        } else {
            throw error;
     });
}
```

Running `new Promise()` is often called by people an anti-pattern. Sometimes you can't easily get around it, but this is a typical case where it's completely not needed.

Any time you call `.then()` or `.catch()` a new promise is returned, and that's the same promise you want to return from your function.

Here is the async/await version, just for fun:

```
async function upload(row) {

  try {
    await Article.requestData(row.schema) // if exists
    await Article.upload.bind(row.article);
  } catch (error) {

    if(error.code == "NotFoundException") { // entity doesn't exists
       await Article.create(row.schema) // create entity
       await Article.upload(row.article);
    } else {
       throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the rewrite but it's not what I'm looking for, the reason and the solution why else clause fails despite the anti pattern, can you please highlight on the actual issue.

Comment: is there a problem with calling reject on the catch section?

Comment: @Developer one major mistake is that you are not returning from several of your promise-chains, which means that if errors are thrown within them, they get 'swallowed' and never handled. All your promise chains should return their result back (as a promise) to the main function. My answer is the sanest solution to that, but if you want to keep your spaghetti version make sure you catch errors from your second promise chain as well.

Comment: Note that in my version, every time i start a promise chain I return it. (Article.requesData and article.upload). But retuning in your case wouldn't do anything due to the use of new Promise, so your only option is to add `catch` clauses to each and pray that no error gets thrown in your final catch clauses

Comment: `one major mistake is that you are not returning from several of your promise-chains` this is valuable. Now I do understand the antipattern and thankfully I've the right approach from you, but just to understand and fix the issue what'd you do to fix my version the way it is with the wrapper promise. It will help me understand better. Please provide a code solution in another edit underneath your given answer. Thanks again.

Comment: My understanding was as long as there's a reject handler towards the end of the chain, an issue anywhere on the chain is handled by the handler at the end. I mean do I need to have a catch after every then or second param to then? Just to point out the `else` clause is giving me pain here (`never handled error`)

Comment: Summary: I've two chains inside the wrapper, the first chain has the catch if entity doesn't exists or if exists then the catch is for possible upload errors (if else clause in the catch to determine that). If it's an upload error it's rejected back to the caller. The second chain is to create the entity followed by upload and if an upload error it's rejected to the caller by `then(resolve, reject)`. My understanding is I'm catching all corners but you said I'm not, that's what I want to know to figure it out.

Comment: @Developer can you tell me which promise is being rejected? The best way to find out is to use my code snippet, because you will get the *actual* correct exception back. With that in hand it might be easier to find out what part of your chain failed.

Comment: the problem is with first chain within the catch clause inside if/else, within else section I either `throw` or `reject` the error, both throw and reject causes the process to break. This catching and rejecting is somehow causing a weird bug that I'm unable to catch at the caller level. Maybe you can ignore the 2nd nested in the question and focus on the else clause, and let me know if the code is technically correct in spite of the antipattern.